Precise form of two-mode squeezed state
Starting with the two-mode squeezing operator
$
S_2(\xi) = \exp \left( \xi^* a_1 a_2 - \xi a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger \right)$, we can factor it into [1]
$$
S_2(\xi) = \frac{1}{\cosh r} \exp\left( -a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger e^{i\varphi} \tanh r\right)   \exp\left[-\left(a_1^\dagger a_1 + a_2^\dagger a_2  \right)\ln(\cosh r) \right]    \exp\left( -a_1 a_2 e^{i\varphi} \tanh r\right)
$$
which, when I apply to the vacuum $\vert 0\rangle _1\vert 0 \rangle_2$ I get
$$
\begin{align}
\vert TMSV \rangle  &= \frac{1}{\cosh r} \exp\left( -a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger e^{i\varphi}\tanh r \right) \vert 0 \rangle_1 \vert 0 \rangle_2,\\
&= \frac{1}{\cosh r}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(e^{i\varphi} \tanh r)^n \vert n \rangle_1 \vert n \rangle_2,
\end{align}
$$
which jives with what I see in the literature [2] [3]. However, in many many other places [4], I also see
$$
\vert TMSV \rangle = \sqrt{1-\eta^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \eta^n \vert n \rangle_1 \vert n \rangle_2,
$$
where $\lambda = \tanh r$ (and $\xi$ is real). For the life of me I can't figure out where  the $(-1)^n$ went. This is obviously not an issue for the density matrix, but it seems like a big difference for the state itself. I don't think it comes down to convention, as the squeezing operator is the same in both cases. Am I missing something obvious?
[1] https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.3093
[2] Introductory Quantum Optics, Gerry & Knight
[3] A Group-Theoretical Approach To Quantum Optics - Klimov & Chumakov
[4] E.g. How to obtain a two mode Squeezed state from two mode squeezed vacuum? and Two-mode squeezing and EPR

Both references [4] use a definition of $S_2(\xi)$ different from yours. In one of the threads in [4], $\xi$ is equal to minus your $\xi$. So you can probably safely use the formulas from sources [1-3].

For me, it sounds a specific choice for the phase $\varphi$, since $e^{i\varphi}$ also disappeared. Look that if $\xi = re^{i\varphi}$, for $\varphi = \pi$ we have real $\xi$ and $(-1)^n e^{in\pi} = 1$.

I considered that but they seem to start from the same squeezing operator, except r is real. E.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323208/how-to-obtain-a-two-mode-squeezed-state-from-two-mode-squeezed-vacuum

Your general expression for any $\varphi$ agree with all reliable sources that I checked and also agrees with your first source, with one of posts in your fourth source. It means it might be right. The only way to get the last expression of it is to considering this specific choice of phase

I would add that for both $\phi=0,\pi$ we have real squeezing factor, but the difference between them is what variable they are "squeezing" (I'm terms of uncertainty).

Look that in this post, there is only one answer, and the author said itself that there are typos on it. I personally don't believe it is possible to get rid of this factor without such specific phasis choice

Yeah I think it's just a case of people copying other peoples' typos. However there are two real parameters that give alternate expressions is insightful and helpful. Thanks for the sanity check.
